# Is there a way to tell which philosophers are correct in their musings?

Tags: epistemology, education

Is quoting an authoritative source a useful or effective way to demonstrate that an assertion is correct?

Comment: I'd suggest the only way is to use your reason. nobody can tell you what is a sensible idea. There are tools for the job but we each have to be our own workman.

Comment: @PeterJ, I agree. That's why our individual thought processes are relevant to philosophy. Thanks.

Comment: It is not the point of philosophy to be "correct", so there is nothing to tell in the first place.

Comment: @Conifold.."*It is not the point of philosophy to be 'correct'*".. I agree. That's a black/white distinction, and these types of adjectives are very often applied thoughtlessly and mistakenly. But why did you bring that up? I wasn't asking about that...was I?..."*there is nothing to tell in the first place*" … Is that a Buddhist perspective? If so it's very deep and wise IMO, but we haven't yet gotten to considering together the empty basis on which all our presumptions rest...have we?

Comment: I consider that adjectives such as I used here (authoritative, sensible, reasonable and wise) aren't binary (like correct or incorrect, true or false), but rather to be assessed as *more or less*, relative to consensual meanings and the contexts in which those meanings are applied (see [black/white fallacy](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/94/False-Dilemma))

Comment: Perhaps change the title, and add a bit more context to the post? One liners are hard to read into, and are discouraged, they are often closed as too broad/vague. "Sensible, reasonable or wise" are also too much in the eye of the beholder, but you could ask about comparative metaphilosophical studies, for example.

Comment: @Conifold.."*Sensible, reasonable or wise" are also too much in the eye of the beholder*"  Huh? I'm bound to presume that each of us ought to speak for ourselves and about ourselves. I find this generality, as a criticism, to be, ummm, overreaching(?) Is that a fair assessment? I don't want to accuse anyone of being overly presumptuous...but this has been a very clear guideline to me for a long time. [Overgeneralization](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/100/Hasty-Generalization] is a philosophical issue, isn't it? Is it too much to ask that people avoid...

Comment: ...dealing with matters of degree as if they're black and white? Is it too much to ask that people refrain from insisting that they know the truth about things about which it's impossible for humans to know the truth ? Is it appropriate for people to insist that they know for certain how others ought to behave, and to insist that citizens conform to authorities which/who  are more concerned with their own beliefs than with actually and actively considering what's better or worse for people? I have my opinions, you have yours, and reconciliation or resolution isn't always possible. IMO !

Comment: This is not a criticism at all, just policy here, we are not passing judgment on the quality of your posts as a piece of philosophy. Your reaction is understandable, and many people have it at first. The thing is that this site has a very limited scope and purpose, [we are not doing philosophy here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/474/9148), paradoxical though it sounds. So no speaking for/about ourselves, just trading references. Opinions are exchanged in forums and chat rooms, one can use this site to make those exchanges more substantive, but it is not for having them.

Comment: this is the most BROAD question i have ever encountered!

Answer (score 2):

Kenneth T. Gallagher described "all truly philosophical questions" (page 34) from the position of Gabriel Marcel as "mysteries" rather than "problems".

Consider the differences between these words:

> A problem, is an inquiry which is set on foot in respect to an object which the self apprehends in an external way. (page 31)

Quoting an authoritative source may be the answer to a problem or question of some object apprehended in an external way. Questions about the validity of symbolic arguments may be examples of such.

> A mystery, on the other hand, is a question in which what is given cannot be regarded as detached from the self....A mystery is a question in which I am caught up. (page 32)

If the philosophical musing is a mystery, such as questions about freedom, the authoritative source would be evidence for the person to consider who will then have to understand the musing not as some object "detached from the self" but as a mystery in which "I am caught up".

Consider the question:

> Is quoting an authoritative source a useful or effective way to demonstrate that an assertion is sensible, reasonable or wise?

If Gallagher and Marcel are correct and the assertion is not a problem but a mystery, then the authoritative source may be useful but the demonstration that it is sensible, reasonable or wise is up to the person who is "caught up" with that assertion as a mystery.

---

Kenneth T. Gallagher. The Philosophy of Gabriel Marcel. 1975. Fordham University Press.

Comment: There are at least two good points here. To me philosophy is necessarily about mystery (as is science). These disciplines are concerned with the value of *inquiry*; they're concerned with considering issues which may never be fully resolved but which may be described in more and more useful ways over time. Second, subjective assessment is a necessary process to consider when figuring out how abstract ideas do or should relate to our actions. Thank you.